# GET method... Extract variables

Tags: php, url-parameters, getmethod

Can someone help me how to extract the url parameters from the following url using GET method in php?

```
http://domainname.com/?formBuilderForm%5BFormBuilderID%5D=29&formBuilderForm%5Brandomizer%5D=508398db941a26.20741366&formBuilderForm%5Bvw_sre_ticker_name%5D=TPX&formBuilderForm%5Bvw_sre_entry_price%5D=100&formBuilderForm%5Bvw_sre_entry_date%5D=21%2F10%2F2012
```

I believe the variable name is formBuilderForm [FormBuilderID] and value is 29. I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$_vw_sre_ticker_name_in = $_GET["formBuilderForm [FormBuilderID ]"];
echo 'vw_sre_ticker_name'.$vw_sre_ticker_name_in;
?>
```

I believe, it something to do with ASCII  and Non-ASCII stuff.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_GET)` and see what you get.  I think you'll need to access some nested values.

Comment: Remove the spaces and try again. Its not "ASCII and non-ASCII", but it is [url encoded](http://php.net/url-encode)

Comment: it will probably be in `$_GET['formBuilderForm']['FormBuilderID']` but it's hard to read... `var_dump` it like seth suggests.

Comment: $_GET['formBuilderForm']['FormBuilderID'] Yep...! it's there. I will complete rest of the stuff and keep you updated. Thanks!           <?php
$_input_form_id = $_GET['formBuilderForm']['FormBuilderID'];
echo '$_input_form_id'.$_input_form_id';
?>                                                                Out put : $_input_form_id 29

Answer (score 0):

`%5D` stands for [ in url encodings

So you could probably try

```
<?php
 $_vw_sre_ticker_name_in = $_GET["formBuilderForm[FormBuilderID]"];
 echo 'vw_sre_ticker_name'.$vw_sre_ticker_name_in;
?>
```

You needed to remove the spaces.

However as pointed out by Seth, this is really really basic debugging a simple

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Would have provided you with the information you needed rather than asking on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did print_r($_get). This is what I have. Now, I need to look how to pull the data out it. I will do some google, but, if you can add your inputs, that would great.                           Array
(
[formBuilderForm] => Array
(
[FormBuilderID] => 29
[randomizer] => 50842bbed1ddf5.08189536
[vw_sre_ticker_name] => tpx
[vw_sre_entry_price] => 200
[vw_sre_entry_date] => 21/10/2012
[vw_sre_submit_button] => 21
)

Comment: When I did var_dump  array(3) {
["formBuilderForm"]=>
array(6) {
["FormBuilderID"]=>
string(2) “29″
["randomizer"]=>
string(23) “508433e46b1696.44351019″
["vw_sre_ticker_name"]=>
string(3) “TPX”
["vw_sre_entry_price"]=>
string(3) “200″
["vw_sre_entry_date"]=>
string(10) “21/10/2012″
["vw_sre_submit_button"]=>
string(2) “16″
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach on $_GET

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
       echo $key . ':' . $value;
}
```